# Setting vertical offset for SLPK layer in ArcGIS Runtime .NET sdk?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net, scene-layer-package

I recently started development of an app using ArcGIS Runtime .NET SDK (WPF). I have an issue related to the the elevation offset for scene layer package (`SLPK`).

When I load my `SLPK` to ArcGIS Online it overlays above the ground, but in ArcGIS Online I can set the elevation offset that corrects the vertical position of the model.

Now if I use the portal item or ArcGIS Online service in .NET WPF app it works fine because my model has been published with an offset.

But I want to load my `SLPK` file local path, and I am unable to find any such option to set the offset value for ground overlay.

```
Uri _serviceUri = new System.Uri(@"D:\Projects\test\lod75.slpk");
ArcGISSceneLayer sceneLayer = new ArcGISSceneLayer(_serviceUri);
myScene.OperationalLayers.Add(sceneLayer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately ArcGIS Runtime does not honor offset on a scene layer in a web scene or expose a property to set the offset for a scene layer, but this is in our backlog to support in an upcoming release.

Things that would be helpful are:

1. Knowing the type of scene layer are you using (3d object, integrated mesh, point cloud, point...)?
2. Knowing how you are creating the SLPK
3. You sharing the scene service and/or portal item you have created with the offset.